# Turn java code to native runnables

Tags: java

I know the answer is probably simple but i have tried many methods nothing worked. I am trying to turn a java code into mac and windows native runnables(exe/dmg)
Now my netbeans ide generates a jar file and another lib folder containing another jar file. What is the exact procedure to turn these files to exe or dmg? 
I tried many tools such as app bundler and launch4j but none worked. I suppose it is because it is NOT a single jar file? Anyone know efficient tool or simple tutorial for this please?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to turn them into natives? The whole (original) point of java was to allow code to run on any machine...

Comment: The main reason is because the program creates dynamic files which need to be stored somewhere in the system and not in the defalut location. This could be specified after i create runnable apps

Comment: I stated these methods do not work because it is not a single jar file so these answers do not really solve my problem

Comment: I'd suggest that you then use `System.getProperty("user.home")`. It returns a String which is a path to the user's "home" directory. (For example, on windows, it would return the `C:\Users\username`).